# Update specific listview item value

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I've a `ListView` like this:

```
<ListView.View>
  <GridView>
     <GridViewColumn x: Name = "KeyColumn1" Header = "Key" Width = "100" DisplayMemberBinding = "{Binding Path=Label}"/ >
     <GridViewColumn x: Name = "ValueColumn1" Header = "Value" Width = "130" DisplayMemberBinding = "{Binding Path=Value}"/>
  </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

The time is defined like: `public DateTime time = DateTime.Now;`

How can I update the time in two different methods? I was able to get the time and display it in `Ringing()`, but the time is not update in `Established()`.

```
private void Ringing()
{
  CallTabLv1.Items.Add(new { Label = "Time", Value = time.ToString() });
  CallTabLv1.Items.Add(new { Label = "Call Type", Value = "Call in" });
}

private void Established()
{
  CallTabLv1.Items.Refresh();
}
```

I know that the simplest way is clear the items and add again in `Established()`, but since there are more than two items need be added, I don't want the code looks lengthy and duplicated. The other way I've thought is remove the specific row and then insert again, but this method is not suitable since my data is dynamic.

Comment: Are you ever changing the value of `Value`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Anonymous Type create a type like

```
    public class LabelValuePair:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool  RequiresTimeRefresh{get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Label) && Label.ToLower() == "time"; }}

    private string label;

    public string Label
    {
        get { return label;}
        set { label = value; }
    }

    private string value;

    public string Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set { this.value = value; Notify("Value");}
    }

    public LabelValuePair(string label, string value)
    {
        this.Label = label;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    private void Notify(string propName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged!=null)
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Ringing method

```
        private void Ringing(DateTime time)
    {
        CallTabLv1.Items.Add(new LabelValuePair("Time", time.ToString()));
        CallTabLv1.Items.Add(new LabelValuePair("Call Type", "Call in"));
    }
```

Established method

```
        private void Established()
    {
        foreach (LabelValuePair item in CallTabLv1.Items)
        {
            if (item.RequiresTimeRefresh)
                item.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Now you wont even have to call Refresh.NotifyPropertyChanged will do that.

Comment: Hi @ethicallogics, thank for the answer,  but it return error: Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.String]' to type 'LabelValuePair'.

Comment: Use CallTabLv1.Items.Add(new LabelValuePair("Time", time.ToString())); instead of anonymous Type in Ringing method

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, is to build an array / list with the columns. Then cycle thru the list and find your 'key'. Whether this key is the primary key or a key of your own design is up to you. I would advise using your own key and creating a custom class, or you will create a mess later when all the lists have their own (or multiple) p-keys.

```
class Columns : MSColumnClass
{
    String        Name;   // name of db column
    CCData        value;  // CCData contains int / long / String / Date
}
class row_data
{
    std::list<Columns>      *m_colum
    long                    row;
    long                    my_key;
}
```